# Aeroplan mileage with mixed booking

Tags: loyalty-programs, united-airlines, air-canada, aeroplan

I have two different trips this summer (YUL-SFO, and YUL-LIM) each booked as a single ticket where one leg is with United and the other with Air Canada (both Star Alliance members). Since I made the purchase on United's website, only the United segment on my confirmation shows any mention of my Aeroplan number.

For example, on the YUL-LIM-YUL trip, YUL-EWR is with Air Canada but EWR-LIM is with United and only that part shows the Aeroplan number.

How does the mileage get credited for the Air Canada legs ? Does it happen automatically after I complete that segment, or do I have to request it at check-in with Air Canada ? Or do I have to request a credit after the trip ?

Comment: Before anyone suggests, I've been trying to get a hold of Aeroplan's customer service since this morning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you booked through United, and flights are with their Star Alliance partners, all the mileage for all legs should be automatically credited to the same account you gave for the United flights.  Save your boarding passes and check after the trip, but this is how it is supposed to work.  I wouldn't worry about it until then.